# print an object without __dict__ as JSON in python

Tags: python

I'm getting data back from a library.  How do I get both the keys and the data in JSON format?

It appears to not have a **dict** property, so I don't know how to inspect it.      vars(obj.rect), fails.

I feel like this must be something super-simple -- I can see the properties (left, right, etc.), but when json just dumps the values, not the keys.

[Edit] user2357112 pointed me in the right direction, so I'm halfway there.  Rect is a namedTuple, printing the json works by adding asdict(), but polygon is a array, how do I encode that as json?  Obviously, I can loop through, but there must be a more generic way.

```py
    print('Rect : ', obj.rect)
    print('rect.json : ', json.dumps(obj.rect._asdict()))
    print('polygon : ', obj.polygon)
    # polygon is an array of named tuples, so this fails.
    print('polygon.json : ', json.dumps(obj.polygon, skipkeys=False))
```

```bash
Rect :  Rect(left=2264, top=1031, width=241, height=238)
Rect.json :  {'left': 2264, 'top': 1031, 'width': 241, 'height': 238}
polygon :  [Point(x=2260, y=131), Point(x=2261, y=367), Point(x=2500, y=360), Point(x=2502, y=119)]
polygon.json :  [[2260, 131], [2261, 367], [2500, 360], [2502, 119]]
```

Obviously, skipKeys isn't the answer.  I've hacked away with .**dict**, but that's not working.  I'm new to python, so not even sure how to debug what Rect and Polygon are.

Comment: you can try introspecting the `vars(obj)` of the object.

Comment: This sounds like a namedtuple, which would have an `_asdict()` method, but we can't tell from here.

Comment: Cha-ching!  Please submit that as an answer, instead of a comment, so I can accept it.

Comment: I was using the json library, not jsons, which is what I was looking for. Sigh.